# What are the ancient (obsolete) names of the "book spine"?

Tags: etymology

What are the ancient (obsolete) names of the "book spine"?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clearly asked, and it’s hard to tell what you are referring to. Are you talking about the _spine_ itself? Or so you mean the extra ‘folds’ that run horizontally across the spines of the books in the image? Or something else? Please edit the question to indicate precisely what part of the boon you’re talking about.

Comment: '*The* obsolete names' implies both that book spines have obsolete names (presumably because everything does) and that there is a clearly defined set of such names. Neither implication is justified.

Comment: The question could have been formulated differently such as 1. What were book spines originally called? 2. What would a 16th century scholar have called a book spine? And then explain why you were asking the question. Questions consisting of only one sentence don't do very well on EL&U.

Comment: The connection between two areas (the covers) is a *bridge*. Perhaps in the booksense, too? I don't feel like flipping through dictionaries for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The English use of '***spine***' for that part of a book is modern, only from the early 20th century. [OED.com](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/186697) [*Note: page might be accessible only from schools or libraries*] gives the first use of this sense of 'spine' from 1922:

> 1922   M. Sᴀᴅʟᴇɪʀ *Excurs. in Victorian Bibliogr.* 14   Be wary of books in cloth which bear no publisher's imprint on the **spine**.

Before that, this part of the book was generally known as the '***back***' [ibid.]:

> The **back** of a book, that is, the part bearing the title, etc., which is visible when the book is standing on a shelf

[back, n.1](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/14332):

> The convex part of a book, opposite to the opening of the leaves.
>
> 1863   *Bookseller's Catal.*   Fine copy, calf extra, full gilt **backs**, marbled edges.

Of course, 'back' is neither ancient nor obsolete, but it may have to do.

Comment: For me the 'back' of a book means the covers which sit next to each other on the shelf and can be made from leather, card, paper or other material. Thus 'paperback', 'hardback' and so on. Did the covers have a different name before the term 'spine' came in?

Comment: @BoldBen As you've said, the word was "covers". OED:  Of a book:  (a) The binding, wrapper, or case, as a whole;  (b) each of the boards or sides, as in from cover to cover;  (c) the quantity of cloth required for a case.

Comment: *back* compares better to *spine* if considering the anatomic meaning. Compare German *Buch-Rücken* "book spine", *Ruck-Sack* "back-pack", *kaputter Rücken* "broken back". It looses a bit in translation. By the way, Inwould be surprised if there weren't any more technical terms, perhaps taken from Latin for example (recto, verso, ... ?)